# Correcting error: by in left_join function in r

Tags: r, left-join

```
edges<-data2 %>% 
 left_join(nodes, by=c("sources"="label")) %>% 
 rename(from=id)
```

For some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: `by` can't contain join column `label` which is missing from LHS
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Try `by=c("label"="sources")`

Comment: Please show definition of nodes

Comment: Please tag properly including wit libraries & look at the formatted version before you post. See my edits. What did you learn googling this error & reading the manual? Please also act on [mcve].

Comment: @Bohemian I have tried that and still no change.

Comment: Are you sure that "sources" is a column in data2 and label is a column in nodes? Because that's what that error generally means